# Align pyplot histogram when all values are in 1 bin

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the reproducible issue.  When plotting an indicator variable in this first example where there is density in both the 0 and 1 state everything looks fine.  (I am going to cut off the x axis from 0 to 1, but left it this way for comparison with next part.)

```
plt.hist([np.append(np.zeros(1), np.ones(9)), np.ones(10)], normed=True)
plt.xlim([0,1.2])
plt.ylim([0,10])
```

[image]

However, if I plot this where all the density is in the 2nd state, all of the sudden the bars shift to the right of the 1.0 marker and disappear if I limit my axis

```
plt.hist([np.ones(10), np.ones(10)], normed=True)
plt.xlim([0,1.2])
plt.ylim([0,10])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamically chosen bins are going to be different for different sets of data. Try adding something like `bins=np.arange(0,1.1,.1)` to the plt.hist() calls and they should come out looking the same.

One of the things plt.hist returns is the list of bins it chose. In the first example, it gives `[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ]`, which is the equivalent of np.arange(0,1.1,.1). The second plot doesn't need to accommodate zeroes since the data don't contain any, and so plt.hist chooses `[ 0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5]`.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind that?

Comment: Yep -- see the edit and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense now.  I was trying to work with bins before, and when I made it an odd number, it showed half of it, but didn't figure it out completely.